# Scope drive.file inconsistency (404 on a publicly shared file)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-js-client

Using this scope (var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';) is leading to inconsistencies. If I try to get a publicly accessible file (shared on another google's drive, by anyone, with status "everyone with link may see"), I get a 404 error. See below:

```
message: "File not found: 11Kf9Ch0f_Dbiw-g9BFjNz9C-qFOb1DMIucrt6J-Z-28."
```

Using the other scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive works, but is a restricted scope that Google doesn't promote. This make no sense to me, as the file can be retrieved even with a simple js request and is publicly available.

```
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'; // works as expected
var SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file';  // throws 404
function getFile(id) {
        get_data = {'fileId': id,}
        var res3 = gapi.client.drive.files.get(get_data).then(
            function(res) {console.log(res);},
            function(err) {console.log(err);}
        );
}
getFile('11Kf9Ch0f_Dbiw-g9BFjNz9C-qFOb1DMIucrt6J-Z-28');
```

I am stuck because I am trying to pick generic templates (like the one with the ID I put here), and edit them on my specific app's file space, and the 404.

See below link, accessible even from anonymous browser:
https://docs.google.com/document/d/11Kf9Ch0f_Dbiw-g9BFjNz9C-qFOb1DMIucrt6J-Z-28/view

Answer (score 2):

Where is the inconsistency? `drive.file` scope is specifically for files that were created by your app, or have been opened by your app in the Drive UI. It's purpose is to prevent your app from seeing into the broader collection of files that your user has. E.g. if I have an app that stores audio clips in your Google Drive, you don't want my app to read through your docs and spreadsheets.

Your two solutions are to use `drive` scope, but that is generally frowned on as being too permissive, or ask your users to open the file with your app.

Comment: I understand, but there is no middle term, and it looks quite wrong to be able to get a file outside of gapi so easilly and be stuck via the API, with 404's. My webapp gets soe templates from shared documents, and uses them to create the users versions. It also creates final documents that it shares with peers, and the sharing also fails with drive.file, with the other peer (who the doc was shared to) is not able to see it via API, only with Google Drive page. To me, this looks illogical, and makes the drive.file scope unusable for lot of use cases.

Comment: There will always be use cases for which the standard Drive permissions model doesn't fit. For these cases you need to create a server proxy which has a broad set of permissions that you further reduce based on your ACL model.